# Adding prefixes to some variables without touching others?

Tags: r, dplyr, prefix

I'd like to produce a data frame like df3 from df1, ie adding a prefix (important_) to variables without one, whilst not touching variables with certain prefixes (gea_, win_, hea_). Thus far I've only managed something like df2 where the important_ variables end up in a separate dataframe, but I'd like all variables in the same data frame. Any thoughts on it would be much appreciated.

What I've got:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame("hea_income"=c(45000,23465,89522),"gea_property"=c(1,1,2) ,"win_state"=c("AB","CA","GA"), "education"=c(1,2,3), "commute"=c(13,32,1))

df2 <- df1 %>% select(-contains("gea_")) %>% select(-contains("win_")) %>% select(-contains("hea_"))  %>% setNames(paste0('important_', names(.)))
```

What I would like:

```
df3 <- data.frame("hea_income"=c(45000,23465,89522),"gea_property"=c(1,1,2) ,"win_state"=c("AB","CA","GA"), "important_education"=c(1,2,3), "important_commute"=c(13,32,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be `rename_at`

```
dfN <- df1 %>%
         rename_at(4:5, funs(paste0("important_", .)))
identical(dfN, df3)
#[1] TRUE
```

We can also include some regex if we want to specify the variables not by numeric index.  Here the assumption is that all those columns that doesn't already have a `_`

```
df1 %>%
    rename_at(vars(matches("^[^_]*$")), funs(paste0("important_", .)))
#   hea_income gea_property win_state important_education important_commute
#1      45000            1        AB                   1                13
#2      23465            1        CA                   2                32
#3      89522            2        GA                   3                 1
```

Or with `matches` and `-`

```
df1 %>%
    rename_at(vars(-matches("_")), funs(paste0("important_", .)))
#   hea_income gea_property win_state important_education important_commute
#1      45000            1        AB                   1                13
#2      23465            1        CA                   2                32
#3      89522            2        GA                   3                 1
```

All three solutions above get the expected output as showed in the OP's post

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility:

```
names(df1) <- names(df1) %>% {ifelse(grepl("_",.),.,paste0("important_",.))}
# > df1
#   hea_income gea_property win_state important_education important_commute
# 1      45000            1        AB                   1                13
# 2      23465            1        CA                   2                32
# 3      89522            2        GA                   3                 1
```

Comment: right I've been sloppy, I can fix it with `names(df1) %>% inset(!grepl("_",.),paste0("important_",.)[which(!grepl("_",.))])` but then it's not really that pretty anymore, so I removed it from the answer

Comment: (even without unneeded `which`)

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409397/assigning-to-temp-variables-inside-of-maggritr-command-chain